# How to prevent an "a" link from release if there is a "click" event failure?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

This is a question that I have a solution, but not an answer. Considering the situation below:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="failure(); return false;">Failure Function</a></p>
```

If the failure functions fails (some execution error), the return statement won't run and the click will release. The result is to reload the page, an undesired result if the link is used as button to do something in the page.

My solution is this:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="try{ failure(); } catch(e) { console.log(e); }; return false;">Failure Function</a></p>
```

It works but I will have to do it always and I don't think it's using the events resources to deal with execution failure. And I think it is ugly! I am wondering if there is some kind of event or setting for the "a" class the will prevent it from reload the page. Also, I don't understand the standard behavior, it is like returning true, null or void for the object so it will continue - usually those types are treated as false, so nothing will happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you want the links only to be executed after they have been verified?

Comment: so why don't you just cancel the event with preventDefault in the function call from the start? Why even bother with return false.

Comment: Sounds interesting, why don't you answer with an example? @messerbill: I don't want the link to be executed at all, just the function.

Answer (score 1):

If that function is failing it will not reach anymore that "return false", so it will return 'undefined' by default, which is similar to true for event listeners. You can use return false directly into your failure function.

```
failure = (e) => {
  try{
    console.log('');
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

<p><a href="#" onclick="failure()">Failure Function</a></p>
```

I also suggest you to modify the code with 'return undefined' and you will see that it will treat it as true.
Here is the codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJgYdV

another solution could be

```
 failure = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      try{
        console.log('');
        //redirect the user here
      } catch (error) {
        //handle the error here
      }
    }
```

Comment: The answer is right but still depends on try ... catch. I will investigate a different approach. So undefined is seen as true, interesting...